# VB6 Application timing

Tags: time, vb6

I am attempting to profile a VB6 application.

Basically I wanted to work out at a method by method level how much time execution is taking.

However VB6 only supports times to 1 sec.  Is there any good way of working out millisecs etc ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although MSDN [says](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172338) [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263387(VS.60).aspx) is only accurate to 1 second, I've found it's better than that in practise.

[GetTickCount](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172338) is typically accurate to [about](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408(VS.85).aspx) 10 to 16 milliseconds. Here's a VB6 declaration.

```
 Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "Kernel32" () As Long
```

The [same Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172338) shows how to use `QueryPerformanceCounter` to get much higher accuracy, if your PC supports it, and if you need it.

Comment: This is what I've always used as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [High-Performance Timer Objects](http://vb.mvps.org/tools/ccrpTmr/) from the CCRP project instead

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right, TimeGetTime is pretty accurate, from winmm.dll.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx